# Using FFmpeg to create a smooth video slideshow from images

Tags: video, ffmpeg, slideshow

a quick question for FFmpeg guru's

I'm just trying to create a very quick slideshow of lots of images, and am experimenting with 4 or 5 per second at the moment.
Problem is, it's lagging after a few images and not displaying them in a consistent manner, and I'm not sure what setting I need to change/get right to make it appear smooth.

From what I understand -r dictates how many frames per second, so 1/0.20 should produce 5 frames per second.
I have a suspicion that the format used may dictate 24 frames a second or something which is causing the momentary hickup.

This example produces a video that goes something like... 1.2.3.4.pause.1.2.3.4.pause

"C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -f concat -r 1/0.20 -i 1.txt -s 1280x960 -vf format=yuv420p video18.mp4

And this example goes something like.. 1.2.pause.1.2.pause.

"C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -f concat -r 1/0.25 -i 1.txt -s 1280x960 -vf format=yuv420p video19.mp4

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've half worked it out via nonsensical posts elsewhere.
From my understanding this should produce 4 images / second, and it appears to work smoothly.

"C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -f concat -r 1/0.25 -i 1.txt -s 1280x960 -vf format=yuv420p -r 10 video25.mp4